# Polymer: <app-header effects="...Internet Explorer Bugs">

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, parallax, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

I'm having an issue with the parallax scroll effects in the Polymer `app-header` custom element. You can see the problem happening in IE10, IE11, and Edge, but Chrome, FF, and Android browsers appear to be good.

**Live Link:** http://sulphurfuelinjection.com/ 
**Source Code:** https://github.com/oneezy/psk-1.5/tree/master/app/src  
**Video (pardon the commentary):** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QISkTfeFRc

--

I think the problem exists with they way I'm laying everything out..though I'm unsure..the `<component-header>` is where the `<app-header-layout>` and `<app-header>` exists and I think* that's where my problem starts:

**Main Layout** [(view source)](https://github.com/oneezy/psk-1.5/blob/master/app/src/business-app.html)

```
<!-- Business Header
------------------------------------------------------------->
<component-header id="Services" grid="vertical" layout="start-stretch" min-height="1"></component-header>

<!-- Business Pages
------------------------------------------------------------->
<component-main id="Main" grid="vertical" layout="start-stretch" min-height="1">

    <page-intro          id="Intro"       min-height="1"    flex="1"    bg="white">        </page-intro>
    <page-company        id="Company"        min-height="1"    flex="1"    bg="yellow">       </page-company>
    <page-testimonials   id="Testimonials"   min-height="1"    flex="1"    bg="gray">         </page-testimonials>
    <page-forms          id="Contact"        min-height="1"    flex="1"    bg="white">        </page-forms>
    <page-outro          id="Outro"          min-height="1"    flex="1"    bg="blue">         </page-outro>

</component-main>

<!-- Business Footer
------------------------------------------------------------->
<component-footer id="Footer" grid="vertical" layout="start-stretch"></component-footer>
```

**Header Component** [(view source)](https://github.com/oneezy/psk-1.5/blob/master/app/src/components/component-header.html)

```
        <app-header-layout>
            <app-header
                id="appHeader"
                class="main-header"
                condenses
                reveals
                effects="resize-snapped-title waterfall blend-background parallax-background">

                <!-- TOOLBAR -->
                <!-- TOOLBAR -->
                <!-- TOOLBAR -->
                <app-toolbar class="top-toolbar">

                    <header-toolbar grid="horizontal" layout="between" condensed-title>
                        <paper-icon-button class="toolbar-drawer" icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>

                        <paper-tabs class="toolbar-links" selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="name" hidden$="{{mobile}}">
                          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">

                            <paper-tab name="{{item}}">
                                <a href="#{{item}}">{{item}}</a>
                            </paper-tab>

                          </template>
                        </paper-tabs>
                    </header-toolbar>
                </app-toolbar>

                <!-- HERO -->
                <!-- HERO -->
                <!-- HERO -->
                <app-toolbar class="hero" title>
                    <header-hero></header-hero>
                </app-toolbar>

            </app-header>

        </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
```